# Neural network periodic cost value change

Tags: c#, neural-network

I am creating a neural network with sigmoid activation function with back propagation, adaptive learning rate and momentum. I am using wine data set.

My main problem is that the algorithm is oscillating around 0.88 cost value or change periodically from 0.88 to 12. I am unable to brake 0.88 value.

I am normalizing all data.

There is link to my repo with it: https://github.com/mikart143/trainbpx-wine-core

Comment: do you mean that 12 is too big? Actually the scalar of cost can not be the fact of problem.

Comment: I calculate cost as sum of squares of errors of last layer. I calculate it at the end of each epoch. In my opinion this can easily tell you if mine neural network is trained well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every learning have a different result because of a random initialization. So, a scalar of cost can be difference by each learning.

If you met some big different result, I think this kind of case as following:
[image]

So, I think that the cost is not a problem.

But, First of all, We have to think about the machine learning algorithm.
An output of Machine learning is not a program what is executed to make the same output always.
So, We do not make a program. We just set an algorithm for an efficient learning by a data and an aim of prediction.

Based on your explanation and code, Your model is multi-class classification.
So, There are some machine learning algorithm for multi-class classification such as the KNN, the Random Forest and the neural network with softmax.

And, the neural network for multi-class classification requires the softmax because that it is more fit than sigmoid.

You know, Sigmoid has 0~1. Actually, it is fit for 0 or 1. So, Usually, It is for the binary classification.
[image]

And, Softmax can give probabilities what sum is 1. So, It is for the multi class classification.

[image]

I saw your code what you are developing functions for building neural network with c#. It's great. But, I can make sure that sigmoid is not enough for your neural network model.

Comment: Thank you for your patient. This is first time when I ask about neural networks. So, my network consist of four layers. First one have 13 neurons because there is 13 parameters. Two discrete layers, first one have 30 neurons and second one have 12 neurons. Last layer is output and have 1 neuron. All data are normalize between 0 and 1. At the beginning I feed first layer than loop iterate over 3 more layers. Then i calculate error and start back propagation where i calculate all data left. At the and I update bias and all weights, also i change my learning rate. My goal to stop is cost < 0.02

Comment: @MikartAerang   is data images?  you need to increase more number of neurons.   And is the activation of hidden layer a relu?   And, is Y is binary what it means 0 or 1?

Comment: Data set link: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/wine 
Why  ? This data set is not so big and not to hard. I do not understand second question. For activation function for all neurons I use sigmoid. In data set there are 3 classes of wine. Class 1 is 0, class 2 is 0.5 and class 3 is 1.

Comment: @MikartAerang  I saw your code.  I think your activation function of hidden layer is a sigmoid too.  I think sigmoid is not enough for mlp.  please try to use relu.

Comment: @MikartAerang   And, If you have 3 classes, A sigmoid can not the activation of ouput layer too.   you have to use softmax.    and you have to use crossentopy as cost function.

Comment: It sound great but my friend was able to create similar neural network to mine without momentum. Also I am trying to base on trainbpx/traingdx from matlab because I was able to create and train network with this dataset. I stucked with this for two weeks. I do not know if I have an error in code or I use wrong things as you said